# How to provide a translation for a string used within t()?

Tags: i18n-l10n

On my site I use a module which creates text using t('text from module'). How can I tell drupal that I have a translation for that, and of course, that my translated text is being displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alternative, on admin/config/regional/translate/translate you can translate any string used by modules installed on that site, and on admin/config/regional/translate/import you can import the translation files.

> [image: admin/config/regional/translate/translate]

> [image: admin/config/regional/translate/import]

Those are the paths for Drupal 7; for Drupal 6 they are, respectively, admin/build/translate, and admin/build/translate/import.

The first page is useful to translate the string provided by a custom module, but also to alter an imported translation, while the second page is useful to manually import the translations exported from a site, such as http://localize.drupal.org.

To automatically get translation strings from [Drupal.org Translations](http://localize.drupal.org) there is the [Localization update](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update); to contribute back the translation to Drupal.org Translations there is the [Localization client](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_client) module. Both the modules have been written by [Gábor Hojtsy](http://drupal.org/user/4166), who is the administrator for Drupal.org Translations.
If you are interested in using both the modules, there is also the [Localized Drupal Distribution](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_install) distribution, which comes with those modules.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you install the **[Localization update](https://drupal.org/project/l10n_update)** module.  It is the key to handling anything that has to do with translation.  Enable automatic translation updates.

If the module is an "official" module with a stable release. the **Localization update** module will pull down translations from [localize.drupal.org](http://localize.drupal.org/) - provided they exist.  If they don't exist, *you* should provide them (read about how you can contribute on [localize.drupal.org](http://localize.drupal.org/)) - and the **Localization update** module will install them for you within 24 hours (if you've enabled automatic updates).

If the module does not have a stable release, there will not be anything on [localize.drupal.org](http://localize.drupal.org/).  In that case, you must add local translations using the built-in translation interface.